# Insertionsort Double linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

Im trying to make a insertionsort for my double linked list. The problem is it gets stuck in an infinite loop and i cant figure out why. I'm relatively new to pointers so i must be missing somthing.

This is the code I'm using to sort it.

```
for (Node* i = m_Head; i != NULL; i = i->Next) {
    for (Node* j = i; j != m_Head;) {
        if (j->Prev == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (j->Value < j->Prev->Value)
        {
            Node* NP = j->Prev;
            Node* N = j;

            Node* NP_prev = NP->Prev;
            Node* NP_next = NP->Next;
            Node* N_Prev = N->Prev;
            Node* N_Next = N->Next;

            NP->Next = N_Next;
            NP->Prev = N;
            N->Next = NP;
            N->Prev = N_Prev;
            

            if (NP_prev == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "NP is head, new head is now N" << std::endl;
                m_Head = N;
            } else {
                NP_prev->Next = N;
            }
            
            if (N_Next == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "N is tail, new tail is now NP" << std::endl;
                m_Tail = NP;
            }   else {
                N_Next->Prev = NP;
            }
                

        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If i want to sort for example the list 5, 3, 7, 0, 2, 9 where 5 is the head and 9 is the tail, it will result in

> 3, 5, 0, 7, 0, 7
>
> 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
>
> 3, 5, 0, 7, 0, 7
>
> 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0

repeatedly in a loop.

The node class looks like this:

```
class Node{
private:

public:
    Node* Next = NULL;
    Node* Prev = NULL;
    int Value = 0;
};
```

Comment: `j` is never incremented.

Comment: To clarify further, there is no third part to your inner for loop. You need three parts to a for loop - the iterator definition (`j = i`), the test (`j != m_Head`, and the command to change the iterator `j`...which is missing.

Comment: *it gets stuck in an infinite loop and i cant figure out why.*  Did you use the debugger?  If you wrote the code, then you should have full knowledge of what you've written.  If the code runs counter to your plan, then you debug the code to see where it goes awry.